# Upgraded spring boot from 2.1.0 to 2.2.2.RELEASE , now getting exception while starting

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0, spring-boot-actuator

I am upgraded SpringBoot version 2.1.0 to 2.2.2.RELEASE

java : openjdk11
spring-boot: v2.2.0.RELEASE
springCloudVersion : Hoxton.RC1

**Error :**

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

**Description:**

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsManager.createContextBuilder(DocumentationPluginsManager.java:152)

*The following method did not exist:*

```
 org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry.getPluginFor(Ljava/lang> /Object;Lorg/springframework/plugin/core/Plugin;)Lorg/springframework/plugin/core/Plugin;
```

*The method's class, org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry, is available from the following locations:*

```
jar:file:/home/cuelogic.local/kanisha.modi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.plugin/spring-plugin-core/2.0.0.RELEASE/95fc8c13037630f4aba9c51141f535becec00fe6/spring-plugin-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/plugin/core/PluginRegistry.class
```

*It was loaded from the following location:*

```
file:/home/cuelogic.local/kanisha.modi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.plugin/spring-plugin-core/2.0.0.RELEASE/95fc8c13037630f4aba9c51141f535becec00fe6/spring-plugin-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar
```

**Action:**

> Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry

**Error caused by**

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
 org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry.getPluginFor(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/springframework/plugin/core/Plugin;)Lorg/springframework/plugin/core/Plugin;
    at
 springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsManager.createContextBuilder(DocumentationPluginsManager.java:152)
    at
 springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.defaultContextBuilder(DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:106)
    at
 springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.buildContext(DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:91)
    at
 springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.start(DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:154)
    at
 org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182)
    ... 101 common frames omitted
```

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    
    compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client"
    compile "io.opentracing.contrib:opentracing-spring-jaeger-cloud-starter:1.0.1"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop"
    compile "org.springframework:springloaded:1.2.8.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-web"
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config"
    compile "org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.1"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.10"
    compile "com.google.guava:guava:${guava_version}"
    compile(group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.7.0') {
        exclude(module: 'guava')
    }
    compile "javax.cache:cache-api:1.1.0"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache"
    compile "com.hazelcast:hazelcast-spring:3.12"
    compile "com.hazelcast:hazelcast-eureka-one:1.0.2"
    compile "org.reflections:reflections:0.9.11"
    compile group: 'io.opentracing.contrib', name: 'opentracing-spring-cloud-mongo-starter', version: '0.3.12'


}
```

How to solve this issue? Please help me it would be grateful.
**I want to upgrade my application to springboot v2.2.2 .So need a solution for this version.**

Answer (score 4):

Update your springfox-swagger version. I have springfox 2.9.2 running with boot 2.2.2

**Edit 98.01.2020:**

You somehow got spring-plugin-core-2.2.0.RELEASE in your classpath. SpringFox needs version 1.2.0, Spring Boot 2.2.2 itself does not pull this in. Can you run gradle dependencies --configuration runtimeClasspath and check which dependency pulls in this version?

Comment: P.J.Meisch Thanks for respond. I have tried with this version but it it not working yet.

Comment: Sir @P.J.Meisch may I know which springCloudVersion have you used?

Comment: I am not using Spring Cloud. Just Spring Boot and a manually added springfox.

Comment: Sir still its not working. Can you please share your code? It would be grateful.

Comment: You somehow got _spring-plugin-core-2.2.0.RELEASE_ in your classpath. SpringFox needs version 1.2.0, Spring Boot 2.2.2 itself does **not** pull this in. Can you run `gradle dependencies --configuration runtimeClasspath` and check which dependency pulls in this version?